# Standardizing variables and interpreting coefficient estimates

Tags: regression, logistic, standardization, lme4-nlme

I standardized my explanatory variables so that each variable has a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1 to improve convergence of the fitting algorithm and putting the estimated coefficients on the same scale for easier interpretation of effect sizes. I built a global mixed-effect models using the glmer procedure with animal ID as a random effect to account for variation amongst the individuals in the data set. After running the global model, I removed the non-significant variables using P > 0.05 and re-ran the reduced model. From this reduced model, I want to make inference to the statistically important variables in the model. I felt like an odds ratio would be helpful in explaining the importance of some of the variables. Any suggestions on my methodology, especially interpreting coefficient estimates that have been standardized? Thank you!